# Excel-IE Automation w/VBA on Dynamic Tables

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping, automation

Good Morning,

I’m hoping that some kind soul out there can help me with a roadblock I’ve encountered in my quest to manipulate a website with VBA. I am using MS Excel 2010 and Internet Explorer 11.0.56.

I’m somewhat comfortable with VBA but have never used it to navigate to a website, enter information and click on buttons. I’ve managed to muddle through as follows:

In Column A of my Excel spreadsheet, I have a list of 10 digit case numbers.

The code below will open IE, navigate to the desired website, pause while I log in, then navigate to the search screen, enter in the first case number and press the SEARCH button (yes, I have the case number in this example hard coded in with no looping, but that stuff I can handle so please ignore):

```
Sub Button_Click()
Dim objIE As Object
Set objIE = New InternetExplorerMedium
objIE.Top = 0
objIE.Left = 0
objIE.Width = 800
objIE.Height = 600
objIE.AddressBar = 0
objIE.StatusBar = 0
objIE.Toolbar = 0
objIE.Visible = True
objIE.Navigate ("https://somewebsite.com")
MsgBox ("Please log in and then press OK")
objIE.Navigate ("https://somewebsite.com/docs")
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until objIE.ReadyState = 4
objIE.Document.all("caseNumber").Value = "1234567890"
objIE.Document.getElementById("SearchButton").Click
Exit Sub
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until objIE.ReadyState = 4
MsgBox ("Done")
End Sub
```

[That will bring me to this screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVl5g.png)

The file number entered in the search field will return any number of files in a dynamic table with a checkbox to the left of each file.

For this example, let’s say I am ONLY concerned with the file called “CC8” under the “Type” column. There will only ever be one instance of “CC8” for a given file number.

What I need help with is, through VBA, how do I search through this table, find the “CC8” line, and then have the checkbox to the left automatically checked?

When I inspect the “CC8” element in IE, this is the HTML associated with it (highlighted in gray; the entire table is under class “listing list-view clearfix”)

[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKiFu.png)

The HTML for the checkbox related to the “CC8” item is below:

[HTML code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHbIi.png)

The “id” for both has the same sequence of numbers, but one starts with “viewPages” and the other “doc”.

Can anyone help me out as to what I need to add to my code to get this checkbox checked? Thank you!

Comment: Please use the snippet tool to insert html as we cannot copy and test from an image. Use the [edit] button to make the changes.

Comment: Include enough HTML that we can see if patterns are repeated across several checkbox items and case hyperlinks.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:**

Please post the actual HTML using the snippet tool.

---

**Generally:**

Without HTML to properly test, I am assuming that the following 2 `nodeLists` are the same length, meaning that when the search text is found in `aNodeList` then the assumption is the same index can be used to target the corresponding checkbox in the `bNodeList`:

```
Dim aNodeList As Object, i As Long
With objIE.document
    Set aNodeList = .querySelectorAll("a[target='_blank']")
    Set bNodeList = .querySelectorAll("[title='Search Result: Checkbox']")
End With

For i = 0 To aNodeList.Length - 1
    If aNodeList.item(i).innerText = "CC8" Then
        bNodeList.item(i).Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

You could also potentially use the following instead as you say the `viewPages` prefixes each item:

```
Set aNodeList = .querySelectorAll("a[id^='viewPages']")
```

---

**Other observations:**

Traditional checkboxes would have a `checked` attribute and syntax of
`bNodeList.item(i).Checked = True`, but as I can't see that attribute in your element I am assuming a `.Click` suffices.

Comment: Well, I can't use objIE.document.getElementById("doc793196159218").Click because that ID changes between each file number. So, somehow I need to identify which ID correlates to the "CC8" link of that particular file number:

Comment: How did you get on with the bottom part?